# How may I find the prediction interval for forecasts using an AR model in R?

Tags: r

I've spent quite a bit of time, and I think that I'm going nowhere. I tried using the prediction intervals in the `predict` method. Here, I'm trying to predict the future values of log returns based on an AR model generated from the log returns.

```
> model_1 <- ar(data1[,'Log Return'], aic = TRUE, order.max = NULL, method = c("mle"))
> predict(model_1, data1[,'Log Return'], n.ahead = 8, level = 0.95, interval = "prediction")
```

However, R refuses to give me any prediction intervals in the output:

```
$pred
Time Series:
Start = 264 
End = 271 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 0.005904645 0.006259840 0.007770717 0.007785322 0.007944444 0.007832193 0.007811966 0.007772691

$se
Time Series:
Start = 264 
End = 271 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 0.009038997 0.009569202 0.009830485 0.009831987 0.009831988 0.009834717 0.009835227 0.009835437
```

I've searched everywhere to no avail, and I'm beginning to suspect that the `predict` method can't give prediction intervals for AR models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we do not have your data, I'll use a model from the `ar` help file and forecast off that.  You don't want `predict` for prediction intervals.  Use the `n.ahead` argument in `ar` and get the prediction interval from the `forecast` package.

```
> (sunspot.ar <- ar(sunspot.year, n.ahead = 8))

Call:
ar(x = sunspot.year, n.ahead = 8)

Coefficients:
      1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9  
 1.1305  -0.3524  -0.1745   0.1403  -0.1358   0.0963  -0.0556   0.0076   0.1941  

Order selected 9  sigma^2 estimated as  267.5

> library(forecast)
> forecast(sunspot.ar, levels = 95)
     Point Forecast      Lo 80     Hi 80      Lo 95     Hi 95
1989      135.25933 114.299317 156.21935 103.203755 167.31491
1990      148.09051 116.455825 179.72519  99.709436 196.47158
1991      133.98476  96.875479 171.09404  77.231012 190.73851
1992      106.61344  68.200200 145.02667  47.865460 165.36141
1993       71.21921  32.673811 109.76461  12.269108 130.16932
1994       40.84057   2.193737  79.48741 -18.264662  99.94581
1995       18.70100 -20.206540  57.60853 -40.802945  78.20494
1996       11.52416 -27.675854  50.72418 -48.427088  71.47541
1997       27.24208 -12.115656  66.59982 -32.950383  87.43454
1998       56.99888  17.600443  96.39731  -3.255828 117.25359
```